# How to make Magento run in my subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

I'm trying to build a Magento (1.9.3.1) staging site in a subdomain but can't get it to work properly. The site is working but no images, js or css files are being loaded. I've searched around but all the answers I've found don't work for me.

My main website structure is www.domain.com which has it's own website (not Magento) but then I have subdomain.domain.com with Magento installed.

Following another answer I tried editing .htaccess and added the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php [L]
```

but that didn't work. I tried different variations of that too.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I have a dedicated server and the domain structure is:

```
/httpdocs
/subdomain.domain.com
```

where the main website root is in httpdocs. Could that be the issue?

The subdomain is set correctly in the core_config_data table as well.

Answer (score 1):

Most packages like magento require root access.. this may be the issue.
Also, try to check the path to youre images.

Answer (score 0):

Okay @Olcan set me in the right direction so thanks. It wasn't actually root access needed but directory permissions were not set correctly.

All the directory permissions were set to 750. Changed them to 755 and everything works. Didn't need to do anything with .htaccess either so I left it at the default

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

and it works.